# fast array operation for creating an array from an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an Array of rows. Each row has an entity object. I want an Array of the entities. Is there a built-in or jquery array op that does this, but faster?

```
var nodes = [];
for( var inx = 0; inx < rows.length; inx++ ) {
    nodes.push( rows[ inx ].entity );
}
```

Comment: Have you got performance problems with your existing code?

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example), but I would echo @Matt's concern with prematurely optimizing your code.

Comment: Why would jquery do it faster than native code...

Comment: Thanks all! The duplicate question is what i was searching for. To answer the questions, no I don't have a perf issue here yet, i was more just looking for a less clunky way to express it: just icing on the cake if it's more efficient i guess. FTR, map is the more syntactically succinct answer i was looking for, but it's actually slower: https://jsperf.com/extract-prop-from-object-array/ .... now i have to decide if i care :)